# Adjust function so that it instead of it looping through all rows, it loops only through all rows within groups

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dplyr

consider the toy dataset and function below:
Basically, it loops through the rows of the dataset `df` and looks for matches according to some criteria. If there is a match, observations are matched by a row number of one of the matches.

```
 dataset <- data.frame(id_dom = c(20, 20, 20, 250, 250, 250, 
                                  254, 254, 254),        
                       p201 = c(1, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, 2), 
                       V2009 = c(63, 42, 64, 26, 5, 4, 69, 30, 68)
                       )
match1 <- function(i, df) {
  j <- 1:nrow(df)
  
  if(!is.na(df$p201[i])){
    l <- df$p201[i]
  } else{
    
    k <-  abs(df$V2009[i] - df$V2009[j]) <= 1
    l <- ifelse(any(k), which(k), i)
  }
  
  return(l)
}
```

This is how I would apply the function:

```
dataset2 <- dataset %>%
  group_by(id_dom,
           index = map_dbl(seq(nrow(.)), 
                            ~ .x %>% match1(df = dataset))) %>%
  mutate(p201 = (first(na.omit(V2009)) - 1)*100)
```

As you can see, my ultimate goal is to pair observations by `index` and `id_dom` - For this reason, it would be much faster (and I think it would also yield slightly better results) if `i` ran through only the of rows of each `id_dom` group, and not the whole dataset.

I would prefer an answer that:

i) Doesn't put the grouping by `id_dom` in the `match1` function but in the pipe.
ii) That allows me to write something looking like `map_dbl(seq(nrow(.)), ~ .x %>% match1(df = . ))` - so that if I create the `V2009` variable before, I don't need to break up the chain prior to running the function.

Thank you!

Comment: I think your `match1` function can be rewritten and made more efficient. Can you explain the conditions that you are trying to implement there?

Comment: @RonakShak I have simplified it a bit in the exemple. But in general, it compares each row ```i``` that have ```p201 = NA``` with other observations  j within group ```id_dom```. If the comparison conditions are met for any of the j elements, the function returns the smallest row index that meets the condition. If not, it returns ```i```

Comment: Ok..so I guess you are not interested in changing `match1` function because this is just a simplified version of the actual function.

Comment: The simplification is only on the conditions for matching, there are multiple conditions relating other columns. But all of them use the same structure of making operations across rows. I would be more than open to change the function if it is still possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cur_data` instead of `dataset` in the `match` after grouping by 'id_dom'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dataset %>%
     # // grouped by id_dom
     group_by(id_dom) %>%
     # // create new group by looping over the sequence of rows
     # // apply the match1
     group_by(index = map_dbl(seq(n()), ~ 
         match1(.x, df = cur_data())), .add = TRUE) %>%
     # // update the p201
     mutate(p201 = (first(na.omit(V2009)) - 1)*100)
```

---

Or use `group_split`

```
dataset %>% 
   group_split(id_dom) %>%
   map_dfr(., ~ .x %>%
                group_by(index = map_dbl(row_number(),
                  ~ match1(.x, df = cur_data()))) %>%
                 mutate(p201 = (first(na.omit(V2009)) - 1)*100))
```

Comment: Oh, I cant check right now, but it looks right. Didnt know about cur_data, nor did of the .add option.

Comment: but since the function uses base R syntax for subsetting, rather than dplyr verbs, will it understand for instance that df$p201[1] means the first observation within a group?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito you could check the output with a group_split (updated)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass only the variables that are needed in the function instead of passing the dataframe. Here is a simplified function `match2`.

```
match2 <- function(x, y, val) {
    if(is.na(x))
      return(which.max(abs(y - val) <= 1))
    else return(x)
}
```

and this can be used as :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dataset3 <- dataset %>%
              group_by(id_dom, index = map2_dbl(p201, V2009, match2, V2009)) %>%
              mutate(p201 = (first(na.omit(V2009)) - 1)*100)

dataset3
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   id_dom, index [6]
#  id_dom  p201 V2009 index
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     20  6200    63     1
#2     20  4100    42     2
#3     20  4100    64     2
#4    250  2500    26     4
#5    250   400     5     5
#6    250   400     4     5
#7    254  6800    69     2
#8    254  2900    30     1
#9    254  6800    68     2
```

This gives similar result as `dataset2` which can be verified :

```
identical(dataset2, dataset3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @RonakShak sorry, I'm not sure if I got the intuition, so I have a question: how would I extend this to have multiple comparisons between rows from other columns?

Comment: You can pass multiple arguments to `match2` function. `match2 <- function(w, x, y, z, val) {........`

Comment: @RonakShak but how would that work? Do I have to use ```pmap``` instead of ```map2```? I wonder in a case where I need ```abs(df$V2009[i] - df$V2009[j]) <= 1``` and some other condition ```df$V1[i] - df$V1[j] == 1```, for instance

Comment: Yes, if you want to iterate over more than 2 values, you can use `pmap_dbl`. Something like `pmap_dbl(list(p201, V2009, V1), match2....)`