# Function inside map_dbl does not give intended result, but works if ran manually

Tags: r, function, dplyr, purrr

I am really confused as to why a function of mine is behaving so weirdly. Here is some data and the function itself:

```
match0 <- function(i, df) {
      df <- as.data.frame(df)
      j <- 1:nrow(df)
    
      if (!is.na(df$p201[i])) {
        l <- i
      } else {
        k <- 
          (!(df$Ano[i] == df$Ano[j] & df$Trimestre[i] == df$Trimestre[j] & i != j)) &
          df$V2008[i] != 99 &
          df$V20081[i] != 99 &
          df$V20082[i] != 9999
    
        l <- ifelse(any(k), which(k), i)
      }
    
      return(l)
    }

dataset <- structure(list(UF = structure(c(11, 11), format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    UPA = structure(c(110000227, 110000227), format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    V1008 = structure(c(1, 1), format.stata = "%8.0g"), V1014 = structure(c(1, 
    1), format.stata = "%8.0g"), V2007 = structure(c(1, 1), format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    V2008 = structure(c(17, 17), format.stata = "%8.0g"), V20081 = structure(c(1, 
    1), format.stata = "%8.0g"), V20082 = structure(c(1969, 1969
    ), format.stata = "%8.0g"), Ano = structure(c(2012, 2012), format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    Trimestre = structure(c("1", "2"), format.stata = "%9s"), 
    V2003 = structure(c(1, 1), format.stata = "%8.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is what I want to do:

```
dataset %>%
  group_by(UF, UPA, V1008, V1014, V2007, V2008, V20081, V20082) %>%
  arrange(UF, UPA, V1008, V1014, V2007, V2008, V20081, V20082, Ano, Trimestre, V2003) %>%
  group_by(index = map_dbl(
    seq(n()),
    ~ match0(.x, df = cur_data())
  ), .add = TRUE)
```

The function should clearly yield `index = 1` for both rows. However, it does not If run the code above. However, If I don't use `map_dbl` and check manually row by row, I get the desired result.

Can someone help me find out why?

Comment: How are you checking it manually row-by-row which gives your expected output? Can you show for these 2 row? Also with `cur_data()` are you trying to pass the row or entire dataset?

Comment: For the second question, I guess ```cur_data()``` refers to the whole df, as in this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63258808/adjust-function-so-that-it-instead-of-it-looping-through-all-rows-it-loops-only/63260965?noredirect=1#comment111889935_63260965). For the first question, I first set ```df <- dataset``` and ``` i = 1``` and ``` j = 1:2 ```  And then instead of running the function, I run each line inside of it to see what value I have for ``` l ```. I repeat the procedure for ``` i <- 2```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?cur_data`

> cur_data() gives the current data for the current group (exclusing grouping variables)

So it passes the data without grouping variables which you are checking for in the function. Current workaround is to pass `cur_group()` with `cur_data()`.

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  group_by(UF, UPA, V1008, V1014, V2007, V2008, V20081, V20082) %>%
  arrange(UF, UPA, V1008, V1014, V2007, V2008, V20081, V20082,
           Ano, Trimestre, V2003) %>%
   group_by(index = purrr::map_dbl(seq(n()),
                     ~ match0(.x, df = cbind(cur_group(), cur_data()))
   ), .add = TRUE)


#     UF       UPA V1008 V1014 V2007 V2008 V20081 V20082 V2003   Ano Trimestre  p201   n_p index
#  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    11 110000227     1     1     1    17      1   1969     1  2012 1             1     1     1
#2    11 110000227     1     1     1    17      1   1969     1  2012 2            NA     2     1
```

In future, there would be `cur_data_all()` which will pass the current data with grouping variables.

Comment: thank you! For some reason, though, this works for the data in the example, but not in the real one. It says: ```Problem with `mutate()` input `index`.
x arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2```

Comment: We haven't used `mutate` anywhere in the code. Not sure what might be wrong but I think this line has a problem and may give problems if not now then in future. `l <- ifelse(any(k), which(k), i)` 1) You should use `if`/`else` here and not `ifelse` since this is scalar comparison. 2) In case there are more than 1 `TRUE` values in `k`, `which(k)` would return more than 1 number.

Comment: The issue persists even by changing the ```ifelse``` thing. I guess ```mutate``` shows up because we actually adding a column when using ```group_by``` that way.

Comment: Hmm...I doubt about that. It would be helpful to debug the issue if you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Not sure how it would help, since the data is the same. The code starts out like this: ```original_df %>% filter(id_dom == 26 & V20082 == 1969) ```. And then it moves on to what I've posted

Comment: Can I reproduce the error based on your data posted?

Comment: I've edited the question with the exact dataset that gives me the error, using dput

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito Sorry, the issue is in `cur_group()`, it returns only one row dataframe. `df = cbind(cur_group()[rep(1, n()),], cur_data())))` should work. But I think the column names in this dataframe is different that the ones used in function. I don't find `p201` column.